# extract file name from full file name

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=src/*.erl
shopt -s nullglob
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
# ???
done
```

How i can extract file name from full path? And what does it mean - "pathfilename=${f%.*}"?

Comment: Your `shopt -s nullglob` should be placed *before* you use glob `*`.. and it is not necessary to save the glob-list of files into a variable and then use that variable in your loop. You can simply (and more efficiently) use `for f in src/*.erl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just copy the help-output, since it has examples and everything.

```
~$ basename --help
Usage: basename NAME [SUFFIX]
  or:  basename OPTION
Print NAME with any leading directory components removed.
If specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

Examples:
  basename /usr/bin/sort       Output "sort".
  basename include/stdio.h .h  Output "stdio".
```

Answer (score 2):

*Update: I've removed my answer to the first part, since apparently I misunderstood what was being asked.*

The syntax you mention, `pathfilename=${f%.*}`, means that `pathfilename` is set to the value of `$f` with the shortest possible match for `.*` removed from the end of the string.  This will strip the extension from the filename.  The [bash manual describes this syntax as follows](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ${parameter%word}
>
> ${parameter%%word}
>
> Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result  of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the "%" case)  or  the  longest matching  pattern  (the "%%" case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is  applied  to  each  positional  parameter  in  turn,  and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with  @  or *,  the  pattern  removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.